# Probability of completing a task along certain path in a certain time using beta distribution

Tags: probability, beta-distribution

I have 5 different tasks and the duration of each task in the network are assumed to be beta distributed and I have their beta parameters (p, q, a, b) for each task. These durations are assumed to be independent of each other.

How do I find the probability of completing the first 3 tasks in a certain time?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do your beta distributions have 4 parameters? The beta distributions I know have only 2 parameters, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Comment: @Maarten The answer to your question is right in the link you gave! click your link and look in the contents under section 3 and [section 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Four_parameters_2) (though the first actual mention of the four parameter case is in section 2; it just doesn't appear in the contents for section 2; sect 7 will be the most directly relevant)

Comment: @DML are these tasks sequential? Or are they being performed in parallel?

Comment: If the tasks are sequential, is the sequence (the order) always the same? Is is randomly chosen 3 out of 5 or always the same 3? Is simulation an acceptable answer for the problem?

Comment: @Glen_b they are sequential.

Comment: @Bernhard they are sequential and the order is always the same, task 1 then task 2 and finally task 3. Any yes simulation would be an acceptable answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a lot of beta distributed variables, the sum will eventually follow a normal distribution. But tree will not be enough to go that route.

If the parameters of the beta distributions are given, then it is very easy to set up a computer simulation of the sum of three such distributions.

In R that would be:

```
# let a to f be the parameters of the beta distributions be know. We assume some random values
a <- 5; b <- 3; c <- 10; d <- 2; e <- 5; f <- 8
n <- 100000

# we draw n triples of beta values and sum them
sum_of_betas <- rbeta(n, a, b) + rbeta(n, c, d) + rbeta(n, e, f)

# Plot histogram of the resulting sums:
hist(sum_of_betas)

# To compute the share of sums that are below 1.5 we can then do
sum(sum_of_betas < 1.5)/n
```

This is simulation, not a closed form solution. The advantage of this is, that it can easily be adjusted to more complicated situations, if needed.

### Edit

Answering the comment: The simulation is based on $n$ replicates. So if you look for small probabilities, you might want to increase $n$ so large, that the simulation output is very similar each time you run the simulation.

In addition to what I coded above, you want beta distributions that do not only range from 0 to 1 but have two more parameters, giving the minimum and the maximum of the distribution. I therefore added variables named `minA` and `minB`and so on for the additional parameters. The code then becomes:

```
# let a to f be the shape parameters of the beta distributions be know. We assume some random values
a <- 5; b <- 3; c <- 10; d <- 2; e <- 5; f <- 8
# let minA to min C be the minimum and maxA to maxC be the maximal values of each beta distr.
minA <- 0; minB <- 1; minC <- 3; maxA <- 1; maxB <- 2; maxC <- 6
# number of random triples is n
n <- 1000000

# we draw n triples of beta values and sum them
sum_of_betas <- minA + (maxA-minA)*rbeta(n, a, b)+
                minB + (maxB-minB)*rbeta(n, c, d) + 
                minC + (maxC-minC)*rbeta(n, e, f)

# Plot histogram of the resulting sums:
hist(sum_of_betas)

# To compute the share of sums that are below 7 we can then do
sum(sum_of_betas < 7)/n
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm a bit confused, what does n refer to? And what are these a to f in terms of the beta parameters (p, q, a, b)?

Comment: Just as @Marten Buis in his comment above, I am used to beta distributions being defined by two shape parameters and values between 0 and 1. You habe two additional parameters for the lower and upper limit which is just a linear transformation. I edited my answer to give code for that. `n` is the number of random value triples drawn for the simulation. Increase `n` if you need more precision, decrease it, if you need more speed for the computation.